# How to add constraints to CALayer programatically

Tags: ios, autolayout, calayer

Do you have any idea about adding constraints to CALayer programmatically?

Comment: Constraints (Auto Layout) comes with UIViews, it has nothing to do with Layers. I would suggest to specifically describe your issue...

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to constraint a CALayer, although you cannot use NSLayoutConstraints. Most flexible way is to sub-class CALayer and override `- (void)layoutSublayers;`. Then you can position and size your content however you want. A simpler and more limited approach is to set the layer's `contentsGravity` property. With this you can set the layer to (for example) always position content in a corner, or do aspect fill.

[Read more about contentsGravity.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410872-contentsgravity)

Answer (score 0):

Constraints is a part of AutoLayout system of UIVIew, so no you cant do this